# Discord suddenly very slow

Tags: 16.04

I updated some programs yesterday, and Discord is suddenly very slow and stuttering. It is only that program, nothing else is affected. The size of the window is a factor as well, if I resize it to be small, the window runs smoothly. This is especially notable if someone posts media in Discord such as a Youtube-link, where it will run very slowly as long as it's windowed in Discord. However, fullscreening it will make it run at full speed with no problems.

Where would I start to find out why it's suddenly running so slow?

Comment: What programs did you update yesterday? Were any of them video drivers... like for Nvidia? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: No drivers. I did a manual update for Brave Browser and Discord, both have in-program updates. I reverted the Brave update, but the Discord behavior remained.

In my update log, I have the following things done that day:
Install: blt:amd64 (2.5.3+dfsg-3), python-tk:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04), scribus:amd64 (1.4.6+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1), libpodofo0.9.3:amd64 (0.9.3-4, automatic), fonts-dejavu:amd64 (2.35-1), scribus-data:amd64 (1.4.6+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1), fonts-dejavu-extra:amd64 (2.35-1), tk8.6-blt2.5:amd64 (2.5.3+dfsg-3), icc-profiles-free:amd64 (2.0.1+dfsg-1), all automatic updates.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I forgot to tag you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It sounds like you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find what caused the slowdowns, but I did a manual downgrade to temporarily fix the problem.

I removed the program through Ubuntu Software, and installed it manually using a .deb of a earlier build, which was available on Discord's own website. The slowdowns are completely gone. I have reported the bug to Discord through their own channels.

EDIT: Discord has 0.0.8, which was a version before the slowdown troubles, on their site: https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb

Comment: I'm not experiencing this problem myself, but others are. Can you post a link to the older .deb on the discord site?

Comment: I have edited in the link @Starbuck

Answer (score 0):

There was an update to discord recently. Be sure you're running the latest version. If you still notice the slowdown after updating, run `top` or `htop` in a terminal. They will show you which processes are running and possibly slowing down your system. You can search "discord" to see only process started by Discord.

Comment: Discord is the program using the most resources currently on my system, according to top. Discord, followed by Brave Browser and kworker. I tried to revert Discord to previous versions by using snap revert, but it is still the newer slow version.